# Why is Github Contribution Graph blue today

Tags: github, graph, themes

Why is the GitHub contribution graph blue?
Is it because of winter?

[image: github Contribution graph image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

seems like there are different colors for the contribution graph. And each time a different color pattern is enabled. Currently it is set to variations of --color-calendar-winter-graph. There are other color patterns like --color-calendar-halloween-graph as well. [github contribution graph styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQDCO.png)

Comment: is this configurable or automatic based on the set calendar?

Comment: I think we can't configure it by ourselves, it is automatic based on the set calendar. It just turned back to green today. To configure the color according to the color we want, I believe there are a few chrome extensions available like [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-contribution-color/cfilkjdlgdiclmdfdggjommndffiibbe?hl=en)

Comment: During Halloween it was set to orange. Since it is the beginning of winter, it was set to blue, is what I'm guessing :)

Comment: damn this was my first question in stackoverflow. I only read before, this feels so good to have a community like that

Comment: This was my very first answer;yes it definitely feels good to have a community, it has more power and warmth than it seems

Answer (score 2):

It could be because December 21st is the Winter Solstice, the shortest day of the year and the official first day of winter. Hence the cold icy blue color.

https://www.almanac.com/content/first-day-winter-winter-solstice